# Cortex M33 missing vector table

Tags: arm, embedded, qemu, cortex-m, bare-metal

I want to test my ARM project within QEMU using semihosting. Initially I built for Cortex A7 and A9 processors and had no issues running my code, however now that I switched to CM33 (and a CM33 board), it breaks immediately:

```
C:\Program Files\qemu>qemu-system-aarch64.exe -nographic -machine musca-a -cpu cortex-m33 -monitor none -serial stdio
-kernel app -m 512 -semihosting
qemu: fatal: Lockup: can't escalate 3 to HardFault (current priority -1)

R00=00000000 R01=00000000 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=ffffffe0 R14=fffffff9 R15=00000000
XPSR=40000003 -Z-- A S handler
FPSCR: 00000000
```

If I understand it right, `PC=00000000` indicates reset handler issues. I thought maybe this  `musca-a` board expects the table to be somewhere else, but looks like it's missing completely:

```
psykana@psykana-lap:~$ readelf app -S
There are 26 section headers, starting at offset 0xb1520:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .init             PROGBITS        00008000 008000 00000c 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        00008010 008010 01d5b4 00  AX  0   0  8
  [ 3] .fini             PROGBITS        000255c4 0255c4 00000c 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 4] .rodata           PROGBITS        000255d0 0255d0 003448 00   A  0   0  8
  [ 5] .ARM.exidx        ARM_EXIDX       00028a18 028a18 000008 00  AL  2   0  4
  [ 6] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        00028a20 028a20 000004 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 7] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      00038a24 028a24 000008 04  WA  0   0  4
  [ 8] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      00038a2c 028a2c 000004 04  WA  0   0  4
  [ 9] .data             PROGBITS        00038a30 028a30 000ad8 00  WA  0   0  8
  [10] .persistent       PROGBITS        00039508 029508 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [11] .bss              NOBITS          00039508 029508 0001c4 00  WA  0   0  4
  [12] .noinit           NOBITS          000396cc 000000 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [13] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 029508 000049 01  MS  0   0  1
  [14] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        00000000 029551 000408 00      0   0  1
  [15] .debug_info       PROGBITS        00000000 029959 02e397 00      0   0  1
  [16] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        00000000 057cf0 005b3e 00      0   0  1
  [17] .debug_line       PROGBITS        00000000 05d82e 01629f 00      0   0  1
  [18] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        00000000 073ad0 004bf4 00      0   0  4
  [19] .debug_str        PROGBITS        00000000 0786c4 006a87 01  MS  0   0  1
  [20] .debug_loc        PROGBITS        00000000 07f14b 01f27e 00      0   0  1
  [21] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS        00000000 09e3c9 009838 00      0   0  1
  [22] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 0a7c01 000036 00      0   0  1
  [23] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 0a7c38 006ec0 10     24 1282  4
  [24] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 0aeaf8 002927 00      0   0  1
  [25] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0b141f 000100 00      0   0  1
```

I'm building with the following options (modified toolchain file from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72199730/qemu-semihosting-doesnt-produce-output)):

```
add_compile_options(
    -mcpu=cortex-m33
    -specs=rdimon.specs
    -O0
    -g
    -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16
    -mfloat-abi=hard
)
add_link_options(-specs=rdimon.specs -mcpu=cortex-m33 -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard)
```

Again, this worked fine for all A processors I've tried, but breaks for CM33. In fact, it breaks for any M core and M core QEMU board.

For the record:

```
 - arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain 10.3-2021.10)
 - QEMU emulator version 7.0.0 (v7.0.0-11902-g1d935f4a02-dirty)
 - Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1645]
 - cmake version 3.22.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guest code has crashed on startup, which is almost always because of problems with your exception vector table. If you use QEMU's -d options (eg -d cpu,int,guest_errors,unimp,in_asm) this will generally give a bit more detail on what exactly happened.

Looking at your ELF headers, it looks like you've not put a vector table into your binary. QEMU requires this (as does real hardware). The usual way to do this is to have a little assembly source file that lays out the data table with the addresses of the various exception entry points, though there are other ways to do this. ([This is one example](https://git.linaro.org/people/peter.maydell/semihosting-tests.git/tree/start-microbit.S).)

The reason you don't see this on A-profile CPUs is that A-profile exception handling is completely different: on A-profile reset starts execution at address 0x0, and similarly exceptions are taken by setting the PC to a fixed low address. On M-profile reset works by reading the initial PC and SP values from the vector table, and exception handlers start at addresses also read from the vector table. (That is, on A-profile, the thing at the magic low addresses is code, and on M-profile, it is data, effectively function pointers).

Note also that the behaviour of the QEMU -kernel option is different between A-profile and M-profile: on A-profile it will load the ELF file into memory and honour the ELF entry point (execution will start from there). On M-profile it will load the ELF file but then start the CPU from reset in the hardware-specified manner, ie without setting PC to the ELF entry point. (This variation is essentially for historical/back-compat reasons.) If you want "just load my ELF file and set PC to its ELF entry point" you should use QEMU's generic loader device, which behaves the same way on all targets, and not -kernel, which generally means "I am a Linux kernel, please load me in whatever random target-specific plus combination of do-what-I-mean behaviour seems best". -kernel is generally best avoided if you're trying to load a bare-metal binary rather than an actual Linux kernel.

[This similar question about getting a working M-profile binary running on QEMU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71486314/loading-an-elf-file-into-qemu/71487910#71487910) might also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I ended up using [CMSIS startup files](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/tree/develop/Device/ARM/ARMCM33/Source/GCC). I also changed `-machine` to `musca-b1` and had to rewrite the FPU initialization code for it to work. Special thanks for `-device loader`, using `-kernel` indeed felt weird.